# Update without page refresh

Tags: reactjs

So I have deployed my app on Heroku I have the url below. When ever I update data my data does not update automatically I usually have to refresh the page or I have to update it twice in order for the new data to appear. below is the url of my app and my code for update.

https://crud-application-x.herokuapp.com/getstudents

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class EditStudent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.ChangeID = this.ChangeID.bind(this);
  this.ChangeRoleNumber = this.ChangeRoleNumber.bind(this);
  this.ChangeFirstName= this.ChangeFirstName.bind(this);
  this.ChangeLastName = this.ChangeLastName.bind(this);
  this.ChangeMarks = this.ChangeMarks.bind(this);
  this.Enter =  this.Enter.bind(this);

  this.state = {
     _id: '',
     role_num: '',
     first_name: '',
     last_name: '',
     marks: ''

  }
}
componentDidMount() {

  /*
axios.get('http://localhost:3200/students/student_info/'+ this.props.match.params.id)

.then(res => {
             this.setState({
               _id: res.data._id,
               role_num: res.data.role_num,
               first_name: res.data.first_name,
                last_name: res.data.last_name,
                marks: res.data.marks
              });
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);

  })
  */
   axios.get( "https://crud-backend.herokuapp.com/students")
    .then((myJson) => {
      this.setState({student:myJson.data});
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
   const student = this.props.location.state;
   console.log('===>Student to edit', student);
   const {
     _id,   role_num,
     first_name,
     last_name, marks,
   } = student;
   this.setState({ _id, role_num, first_name, last_name, marks});

}
 ChangeID(a) {
 this.setState({
   _id: a.target.value
 })
}

ChangeRoleNumber(a) {
  this.setState({
  role_num: a.target.value
  })
}

ChangeFirstName(a) {
  this.setState({
    first_name: a.target.value
  })
}
ChangeLastName(a) {
  this.setState({
    last_name: a.target.value
  })
}
ChangeMarks(a) {
  this.setState({
    marks: a.target.value
  })
}
Enter(a) {
a.preventDefault();

const myobj = {
  _id: this.state._id,
  role_num: this.state.role_num,
  first_name: this.state.first_name,
  last_name: this.state.last_name,
  marks: this.state.marks

};
axios.post('https://crud-backend.herokuapp.com/students/updateStudent', myobj)

.then(res=> console.log(res.data));
  this.props.history.push('/getstudents');
}

  render() {
    console.log('Student in state ===>', this.state);
return(
  <div style={{marginTop:50}}>
      <h2>Update Student</h2>
      <form onSubmit={this.Enter}>
        <div className = 'form-group'>
           <label>Enter ID: </label>
           <input type = "text" className ='form-control' value= {this.state._id || ''} onChange={this.ChangeID}
           />

          </div>
          <div className = 'form-group'>
             <label>Enter Role Number: </label>
             <input type = "text" className ='form-control'  value= {this.state.role_num || ''} onChange={this.ChangeRoleNumber} />
            </div>
            <div className = 'form-group'>
               <label>Enter First Name : </label>
               <input type = "text" className ='form-control'value= {this.state.first_name  || ''} onChange={this.ChangeFirstName}/>
              </div>
              <div className = 'form-group'>
                 <label>Enter Last Name: </label>
                 <input type = "text" className ='form-control'value= {this.state.last_name  || ''} onChange={this.ChangeLastName}/>
                </div>
                <div className = 'form-group'>
                   <label>Enter Marks: </label>
                   <input type = "text" className ='form-control'value= {this.state.marks || ''} onChange={this.ChangeMarks}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className = 'form-group'>
                     <input type = "submit" className ='btn btn-primary'value= "Edit Student"/>
                    </div>

      </form>

  </div>

)
}
}
```

So I have tested this method out before and it was updating without a page refresh. But for some reason I do not know why it is not working any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two approaches you can take to have the app display the updated values.

1) You can have the POST return an updated array of values that you can use those values to update your app state without making another HTTP request.

2) You can make a second request to the BE to fetch the data once the POST request succeeds.

```
axios.post('https://crud-backend.herokuapp.com/students/updateStudent', myobj)

.then(res=> console.log(res.data));
  // update state here by making a call to the BE to get the updated student vallues. 
   axios.get( "https://crud-backend.herokuapp.com/students")
    .then((myJson) => {
      this.setState({student:myJson.data});
     })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
   }
```